# Looping through a string in batch files (enableDelayedExpansion)

Tags: string, batch-file

I hope you can help me with my code below... I am already using enableDelayedExpansion but I wonder why the output is still all the same with my previously used parameters:

For example if i run my script with parameters SERVERS:ALL, I was expecting it to output SERVERS and ALL, but it is always displaying the first parameters when I run them for the first time. Thoughts?

```
set flag=false
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
IF [%1] == [] (
  set flag=false
) else (
  set string=%1
  echo String: !string!
  set flag=true
  for %%x in (%string::= %) do (
    echo VAL is: %%x
    endlocal
  )
)

:END
popd
echo Ending %jobname% ... %check%
exit %check%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without delayed expansion. I left out the flags because they serve no noticable purpose.

```
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="" (
   echo.input string=%~1
   call :ParseString "%~1"
   )
goto :eof

:ParseString
rem %1=string
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('echo(%~1') do (
   echo VAL is: %%a
   call :ParseString "%%b"   
   )
goto :eof
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! This is a great alternative without using the tricky "enableDelayedExpansion" functionality!!!